# How to check a list for duplicates and add values if there are any?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm totally beginner with coding and just need help with some stuff.

My dream was to write a smart shopping list that automatically detects duplicates and increases the weight of duplicate products.

I get the shopping list from an external file which has the following form:

weight\n
ingredient\n
eg.

```
60
eggs
120
beef meat
25
pasta
120
eggs
```

etc...

After converting this files to dictionaries by this code:

```
    final_list = []


def get_list(day_list):
    for day in range(len(day_list)):
        day += 1
        day_to_open = f'Days/day{str(day)}.txt'
        with open(day_to_open, 'r') as file:
            day1 = file.readlines()

        day1 = [item.rstrip() for item in day1]
        x = 0
        y = 1
        list = []
        for item in range(0, len(day1), 2):
            dictio = {day1[y]: day1[x]}
            x += 2
            y += 2
            list.append(dictio)
        final_list.append(list)
    list = []
    for item in final_list:
        list += item
    return list


days = [1, 2, 3]

list = get_list(day_list=days)
```

Finally I get list of dictionaries like that:

```
[{'eggs': '60'}, {'beef meat': '120'}, {'pasta': '25'}, {'eggs': '120'}]
```

How can I iterate through the dictionary to check if any products are repeating, and if so leave one with the added weight?

For three weeks I have been trying to solve it, unfortunately to no avail.

**Thank you very much for all your help!**

#Edit
my goal is to make it look like this:

```
[{'eggs': 180}, {'beef meat': 120}, {'pasta': 25}]
```

#egg weight added (120 + 60)#

Comment: Why not just have a single `dict` with all the keys? You're making a `list` of single element `dict`s, but there's no clear reason to do so; seems like a single `dict` (or subclass like `collections.Counter` or `collections.defaultdict(int)`) would do the job better.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Best not to use `list` as a var name, it's a builtin function. "leave one with the added weight?" -- what does this actually look like? As mentioned, it seems best to key the dict by the name which points to the weight to avoid repeatedly searching your list.

Comment: @ggorlen ~ I meant that there should be one with all reps added together.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you very much, I will try it out as soon as I get home <3

Comment: It's a good idea to actually show what this looks like "all reps added together". It's less helpful to you and future visitors if we have to guess your output, make a wrong assumption and wind up having to do a lot of back-and-forth to get you to your goal.

Answer (score 0):

```
lis = [{'eggs': '60'}, {'beef meat': '120'}, {'pasta': '25'}, {'eggs': '120'}]
# make 1 dict from list of dicts and update max value
new = {}
for d in lis:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if (k not in new) or (int(v) > int(new[k])):
            new[k] = v
# rebuild list of dicts
lis = [{k:v} for k, v in new.items()]
print(lis)
# [{'eggs': '120'}, {'beef meat': '120'}, {'pasta': '25'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

As ShadowRanger has pointed out, it's not common practice to have a list of multiple dictionaries as you have done. Dictionaries are very useful if used correctly.

I'm not entirely sure the structure of the files you are reading, so I will just explain a way forward and leave it up to you to implement it. What I would suggest is that you first initiate a dictionary with all the necessary keys (ingredients in your case) with each of the values set to 0 (as an integer or float, rather than a string), so you would get a dictionary like this:

```
shopping_list = {'eggs': 0, 'beef meat': 0, 'pasta': 0}
```

Then, you will be able to access each of the values by calling the shopping_list dictionary and specifying the key of interest. For example, if you wanted to print the value of eggs, you would write:

```
print(shopping_list['eggs']) # this would return 0
```

You can then easily increase/decrease a value of interest; for example, to add 10 to pasta, you would write:

```
shopping_list['eggs'] += 10
```

Using this method, you can then iterate through each of your items, select the ingredient of interest and add the weight. So if you have duplicates, it will just add to the same ingredient. Again, I'm not sure the structure of the files you are reading, but it would be something along the lines of:

```
for ingredient, weight in file:
    shopping_list[ingredient] += weight
```

Good luck for your dream - all the best!